# What is Revenue Attribution in Customizable Campaign Influence?

Tags: campaign

In 'Customizable Campaign Influence' documentation, its written that there are two types of Record Preference for the model -

1. To create records every time a campaign touches an opportunity, choose All Records.
2. To create records only when the **revenue attribution is more than 0%, choose Records With >0% Attribution**.

My question is, what exactly is the "**Revenue Attribution**". How would I know whether a campaign has attribution more than 0%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some R&D, I've found that to create Customize Campaign Influence we need to use the Trigger/Flow processes. That actually answered my question.